# Is it possible to get a glimpse of whole of geometry before choosing a branch of it?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question

Is it even possible to get a general idea of different fields in geometry before I choose a branch to focus upon, and if so, can someone give me a suggestion for topics that I must read before I settle on some? (Sorry if this question sounds too broad for this site.)

**Details:**
For context, I am a final year undergraduate student who seems to be interested in Geometry and Topology (especially, the branches like Differential Geometry rather than Algebraic Geometry.) I had always found geometry really interesting and thus during my undergraduate years I took courses and also tried to read about different fields in it. The courses included the ones like *Manifolds* and *Algebraic Geometry*. After spenting quite some time on them (during which I covered, the book *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring Tu and the first chapter of Hartshorne.) I seemed to find Manifolds more to my taste rather than Algebraic Geometry one which I found to have, I am sorry to say, no intuition at all, and not at all according to my taste. I also learned a bit of Algebraic topology with topics like Homotopy, Simplicial complexes, Homology etc. Nowadays, I am trying to read about Riemannian Geometry.

Nowadays, I am afraid that even though I love the topics I usually read, and wants to read more about them, it might not even be possible for me to even get a proper glimpse of what is there in all of Geometry before, say, trying to settle on a topic for research (if all goes well, I want to start the PhD within two years), which is what my eventual aim is.

So basically, is there a list of topics that I could go through before I choose something?

Comment: I advise you the 2 volumes entitled... "Geometry" by Marcel Berger, with many appealing figures (which alas are almost absent in some books containing the word "geometry" in their title). [First volume referenced here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540116585).

Comment: @Jean Marie Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it. And yes, figures and more geometric intuition about what is being done is something that I love to read. :)